# What does "Standard" mean in the datatype column of describe

Tags: oracle, types, describe

if you

```
Describe dbms_transform

PROCEDURE COMPUTE_TRANSFORMATION
 Argument Name                  Type                    In/Out
 ------------------------------ ----------------------- ------
 MESSAGE                        STANDARD                IN    
 TRANSFORMATION_SCHEMA          VARCHAR2                IN    
 TRANSFORMATION_NAME            VARCHAR2                IN    
 TRANSFORMED_MESSAGE            STANDARD                OUT
```

What does the STANDARD mean there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type is "<ADT_1>" which is defined in package *standard*.

According to the [reference](http://www.psoug.org/reference/standard.html) these

> data types are generics, used
>   specially within package STANDARD and
>   some other Oracle packages. They are
>   protected against other use; sorry.
>   True generic types are not yet part of
>   the language.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Data Type?

http://www.psoug.org/reference/dbms_transform.html

Comment: Yeh, I saw that... But I'd like to see something definitive. That site turned Standard into ADT but is that correct. Are there other place that *I* can use Standard?